# How do you override a ModelViewSet's get_queryset in Django Rest Framework 3?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I used to follow this pattern in Django Rest Framework (DRF) 2:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class FooSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('url')

class FooViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Foo.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    serializer = FooSerializer
    model = Foo # <-- the way a ModelViewSet is told what the object is in DRF 2

[ in urls.py]
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('Foo', views.FooViewSet)
```

In DRF 3, I now get:

```
AssertionError at /
`base_name` argument not specified, and could not automatically  
 determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a   
`.queryset` attribute.
```

How is `get_queryset` overridden for an instance of `rest_framework.viewsets.ModelViewSet`?

Comment: queryset = YourModel.objects.none()
then define your override for get_queryset.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Figured this one out.  The `model` field of the `rest_framework.viewsets.ModelViewSet` does seem to be AWOL in DRF3.  Now, if you override `get_queryset` you need to specify a third parameter to `routers.DefaultRouter().register` which is the `basename` parameter.  Then, the function won't go off and try to find it on the non-existent `queryset` field of the `ModelViewSet`.

e.g.

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
[...]
router.register('/rest/FooBar'/, views.FooBarViewSet, 'foobar-detail')
                                                     #^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I suggest use my answer, is quite cleaner.  Try it.

Comment: Here is the relevant documentation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage

Comment: I have fallen in same problem. I haven't got your answer. Could you please give details answer?

Comment: In your `urls.py` file, you create a router like `router = routers.DefaultRouter()`.  Then you call `router.register()` on each of your viewsets.  When you call `router.register()`, you must provide a third parameter like `foobar-detail`.  e.g. `router.register('/rest/FooBar'/,  views.FooBarViewSet, 'foobar-detail')`

Comment: As stated in the [django-rest-framework docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#using-with-views-that-do-not-include-a-queryset-attribute), you can use a queryset sentinel to ensure model permissions work correctly and to provide a base name for routing purposes. i.e. add `queryset = Foo.objects.none()` and continue to override `get_queryset()`.

Comment: @a'r Your comment should be a separate answer

Comment: I found I needed to set the base name to just `'foobar'` rather than `'foobar-detail'`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Ross Rogers' answer, on current version (`3.8.2`), you can specify only the model's name instead of the handler. So, instead of:

```
router.register('/rest/FooBar', views.FooBarViewSet, base_name='foobar-list')
router.register('/rest/FooBar/{pk}', views.FooBarViewSet, base_name='foobar-detail')
```

You can just do:

```
router.register('/rest/FooBar', views.FooBarViewSet, base_name='foobar')
```

Comment: very nice clarification

Comment: Great answer, but the name of the parameter is basename='foobar', without the underscore. djangorestframework==3.14.0

Answer (score -3):

To overrite default queryset in DRF 3, just define `queryset` attribute whitin your `FooViewSet` class.

```
class FooViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     queryset = Foo.objects.all()
```

Comment: `get_queryset()` is available so you can do filtering on a per-request basis.  If `Foo` had a `User`  field, then I could define `get_queryset()` to return `Foo.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)`.  Thus, I do need to define `get_queryset()` instead of the static `queryset` field.

Comment: I realize my example wasn't clear as to my intent, apologies.

Comment: @RossRogers no probem, if you want a dynamic queryset using router,you should use your approach.